# PHP, SQL Insert no works

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i would like to know why i am not able to insert new data to my Database. 
in vardump i get good result but nothing is added to my database

> Database : c_id = AutoInc. | a_id | u_id | c_head | c_content | c_date
>   =TIMESTAMP

```
if (isset($_POST['c_submit'])) {
   $sql_najdi_prihlaseneho_uzivatela = "SELECT * FROM users where u_name = '$_SESSION[username]'";
   $vysledokHladania = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $sql_najdi_prihlaseneho_uzivatela);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($vysledokHladania) == 1) {
       while ($db_data_prihlaseneho_uzivatela = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vysledokHladania)) {
            $sql_vloz_komentar = "INSERT INTO comments (a_id, u_id, c_head, c_content, c_date) VALUES ($_GET[a_id], $db_data_prihlaseneho_uzivatela[u_id], $_POST[c_hlavicka], $_POST[c_obsah], 'NOW()')";
            mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $sql_vloz_komentar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a) Use prepared statements to be saver from SQL injections. b) check `mysqli_error()` to see what is wrong with your query.

Comment: Also, doing a `count()` on a `myqsli_result` object doesn't make sense, you should check for the number of rows found.

Comment: @Sirko mysqli_error doesnt give anything

Comment: I would have guessed, that some of the values needed to be enclosed in `'`. What is the return value of your `mysqli_query()` calls?

Comment: @Sirko  bool(false) so problem is SQL command but idk where =\

Comment: Have you tried just echo'ing and manually execute them?

Comment: tryed vardumb SQL command and all was good only NOW() was as NOW() other values was perfect

Comment: I do not say you should just look at the query, but try to execute it in your database manually.

Comment: all good problem is maybe NOW() this is SQL function but idk how to check it if it works =\

Comment: "all good" means what? You were able to fix your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date('Y-m-d h:i:s')` to store current date time in our DB by PHP code and in your query you just missed to put **''** in array index.
Try this one

```
if (isset($_POST['c_submit'])) {
    $date=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    $sql_najdi_prihlaseneho_uzivatela = "SELECT * FROM users where u_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
    $vysledokHladania = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $sql_najdi_prihlaseneho_uzivatela);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($vysledokHladania) == 1) {
        while ($db_data_prihlaseneho_uzivatela = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vysledokHladania)) {
            $sql_vloz_komentar = "INSERT INTO comments (a_id, u_id, c_head, c_content, c_date) VALUES 
                                (".$_GET['a_id'].",".$db_data_prihlaseneho_uzivatela['u_id']." ,".$_POST['c_hlavicka']." ,".$_POST['c_obsah']." ,$date)";
            mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $sql_vloz_komentar);
        }
    }
}
```

I thing it will help you.

Comment: interesting so i sgould schange Database colum TIME STEMP to DATE ? or simple varchar / Text ?

Comment: simply change your  Database colum to  varchar .

Comment: no works =\ maybe problem is in a_id cause it have relationship with another database table its INT from 1 to ...

Comment: @Patrik Horváth okay then you need to get that `a_id ` value first from that relational table then insert it to your current table.

Comment: and value from $_GET is not okey ?

Comment: then fix you value you are passing in get methode

Comment: it is Every value when i vardumb or echo them are good and perfect maching but it wont Insert it to database =\ SQL returning bool FALSE

Comment: Fixed it need store value from $_POST to any variable like $example = $_POST['s']   then SQL passes :)

Answer (score 0):

do you escape the varchar character ? 
Other posible error is the date format  in database.
Post`echo $sql_vloz_komentar` for view the insert statement and the structure of table

```
if (isset($_POST['c_submit'])) {
   $sql_najdi_prihlaseneho_uzivatela = "SELECT * FROM users where u_name = '$_SESSION[username]'";
   $vysledokHladania = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $sql_najdi_prihlaseneho_uzivatela);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($vysledokHladania) == 1) {
       while ($db_data_prihlaseneho_uzivatela = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vysledokHladania)) {
            $sql_vloz_komentar = "INSERT INTO comments (a_id, u_id, c_head, c_content, c_date) VALUES ($_GET[a_id], $db_data_prihlaseneho_uzivatela[u_id], '$_POST[c_hlavicka]', '$_POST[c_obsah]', 'NOW()')";
            mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $sql_vloz_komentar);
        }
    }
}
```